# C# JSON.Net parse and get list of all elements matching a value using LINQ

Tags: c#, json, linq

I'm having trouble finding the correct method for getting a list of json arrays from JObject.

 `_name` element inside the array should be equal to `foo`.

This is the sample json:

```
{
    "doc": [{
        "bob": [{
            "tom": [{
                "frank": [{
                    "category": [{
                        "_name": "foo",
                        "letters": "abc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_name": "foo",
                        "letters": "def"
                    },
                    {
                        "_name": "foo",
                        "letters": "ghi"
                    },
                    {
                        "_name": "foo",
                        "letters": "jkl"
                    }]
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

And here's my code so far:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"D:/Client/data.json"));

var results = from x in o["doc"].Children()
              where x["_name"].Value<string>() == "foo"
              select x;
```

I get this error:

```
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source"
```

**How do I get a list in which each element will be an array containing "_name" and "letters"?**

Comment: I meant "_name" not "_id", fixed

Comment: Is it really your intention to have `doc.bob` be an array containing an object with a property `tom` which has a property `frank`?

Comment: It's not mine JSON, it's from somewhere else. I simplified it. I get it as Json feed every couple of seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three problems:

- You don't want the *direct* children of `doc`, you want the descendants.
- You're using `x["_name"].Value<string>()` even if there *is* no `_name` property
- You're using `x["_name"].Value<string>()` even on non-object children

These are all easily fixed though:

```
var doc = (JContainer) o["doc"];
var results = doc.Descendants()
                 .OfType<JObject>()
                 .Where(x => x["_name"] != null &&
                             x["_name"].Value<string>() == "foo");
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I must have misunderstood, because in documentation it says: "Returns a collection of child tokens of every array in the source collection." and I thought "child tokens of every array" will work.