# Deserialize Complex Json in C# using Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have some complex JSon that I am trying to parse into something meaningful. I'm attempting to deserialize using C# [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) but I can't get the values that I need. What I need is the value from every ColData node except those in a "summary" section. I am able to deserialize into an object using but I am stuck there.

```
    string pandltext = @"{
  "Header": {
    "Time": "2017-08-24T08:32:58-07:00",
    "ReportName": "ProfitAndLoss",
    "ReportBasis": "Accrual",
    "StartPeriod": "2017-06-01",
    "EndPeriod": "2017-06-30",
    "SummarizeColumnsBy": "Total",
    "Currency": "USD",
    "Option": [
      {
        "Name": "AccountingStandard",
        "Value": "GAAP"
      },
      {
        "Name": "NoReportData",
        "Value": "false"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Columns": {
    "Column": [
      {
        "ColTitle": "",
        "ColType": "Account",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "account"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ColTitle": "Total",
        "ColType": "Money",
        "MetaData": [
          {
            "Name": "ColKey",
            "Value": "total"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Rows": {
    "Row": [
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Income"
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Design income",
                  "id": "82"
                },
                {
                  "value": "975.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Discounts given",
                  "id": "86"
                },
                {
                  "value": "-30.50"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Landscaping Services",
                    "id": "45"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "360.00"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Job Materials",
                          "id": "46"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "value": "Fountains and Garden Lighting",
                              "id": "48"
                            },
                            {
                              "value": "550.00"
                            }
                          ],
                          "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "value": "Plants and Soil",
                              "id": "49"
                            },
                            {
                              "value": "1820.72"
                            }
                          ],
                          "type": "Data"
                        },
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "value": "Sprinklers and Drip Systems",
                              "id": "50"
                            },
                            {
                              "value": "30.00"
                            }
                          ],
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Job Materials"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": "2400.72"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "type": "Section"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Landscaping Services"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "2760.72"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "type": "Section"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Pest Control Services",
                  "id": "54"
                },
                {
                  "value": "-100.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Sales of Product Income",
                  "id": "79"
                },
                {
                  "value": "44.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Services",
                  "id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "value": "400.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Total Income"
            },
            {
              "value": "4049.22"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "Income"
      },
      {
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Gross Profit"
            },
            {
              "value": "4049.22"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "GrossProfit"
      },
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Expenses"
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Automobile",
                    "id": "55"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "19.99"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Fuel",
                        "id": "56"
                      },
                      {
                        "value": "179.15"
                      }
                    ],
                    "type": "Data"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Automobile"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "199.14"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "type": "Section"
            },
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Job Expenses",
                    "id": "58"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "108.09"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "Header": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Job Materials",
                          "id": "63"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": ""
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "Rows": {
                      "Row": [
                        {
                          "ColData": [
                            {
                              "value": "Decks and Patios",
                              "id": "64"
                            },
                            {
                              "value": "88.09"
                            }
                          ],
                          "type": "Data"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "Summary": {
                      "ColData": [
                        {
                          "value": "Total Job Materials"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": "88.09"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "type": "Section"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Job Expenses"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "196.18"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "type": "Section"
            },
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Legal & Professional Fees",
                    "id": "12"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Accounting",
                        "id": "69"
                      },
                      {
                        "value": "75.00"
                      }
                    ],
                    "type": "Data"
                  },
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Lawyer",
                        "id": "71"
                      },
                      {
                        "value": "100.00"
                      }
                    ],
                    "type": "Data"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Legal & Professional Fees"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "175.00"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "type": "Section"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Maintenance and Repair",
                  "id": "72"
                },
                {
                  "value": "185.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Meals and Entertainment",
                  "id": "13"
                },
                {
                  "value": "5.66"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Rent or Lease",
                  "id": "17"
                },
                {
                  "value": "900.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            },
            {
              "Header": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Utilities",
                    "id": "24"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": ""
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Rows": {
                "Row": [
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Gas and Electric",
                        "id": "76"
                      },
                      {
                        "value": "114.09"
                      }
                    ],
                    "type": "Data"
                  },
                  {
                    "ColData": [
                      {
                        "value": "Telephone",
                        "id": "77"
                      },
                      {
                        "value": "74.36"
                      }
                    ],
                    "type": "Data"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Summary": {
                "ColData": [
                  {
                    "value": "Total Utilities"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "188.45"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "type": "Section"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Total Expenses"
            },
            {
              "value": "1849.43"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "Expenses"
      },
      {
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Net Operating Income"
            },
            {
              "value": "2199.79"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "NetOperatingIncome"
      },
      {
        "Header": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Other Expenses"
            },
            {
              "value": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "Rows": {
          "Row": [
            {
              "ColData": [
                {
                  "value": "Miscellaneous",
                  "id": "14"
                },
                {
                  "value": "916.00"
                }
              ],
              "type": "Data"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Total Other Expenses"
            },
            {
              "value": "916.00"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "OtherExpenses"
      },
      {
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Net Other Income"
            },
            {
              "value": "-916.00"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "NetOtherIncome"
      },
      {
        "Summary": {
          "ColData": [
            {
              "value": "Net Income"
            },
            {
              "value": "1283.79"
            }
          ]
        },
        "type": "Section",
        "group": "NetIncome"
      }
    ]
  }
}


// Deserialize to object
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProfitLoss.Rootobject>( pandltext );
```

I've tried querying a JContainer like is mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230900/c-sharp-json-net-parse-and-get-list-of-all-elements-matching-a-value-using-linq). I've tried deserlializing a fragment like is mentioned [in the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm) and I've tried using linq as mentioned [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) in the documentation. So far all of my efforts have met varying degrees of "success" but none have yielded the values I'm trying to get. Eventually this data will be bound to a WPF DataGrid for viewing.

Edit:
Added entire Json file

These are a couple attempts to get *something*, but I run into null values in both cases.

```
        // This always returns null
        var results2 = doc.Descendants()
                    .OfType<JObject>()
                    .Where( x => x[ "value" ] != null );


        // This gives me a null exception error 
        var doc1 = ( JContainer ) o[ "Rows" ];
        foreach ( var row in rootObj.Rows.Row )
        {
                // Get a null exception
                foreach ( var row2 in row.Rows.Row )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( row2.ToString() );
                }

        }
```

Edit 2:
Using what @Eser gave as a starting point, I am able to get a list of values, but unfortunately it's just a list of values. Instead of getting something like

```
"Design income", "975.00"
"Discounts given", "-30.50"
```

I get

```
"Design income"
"975"
"Discounts given"
"-30.50"
```

Here is the code I'm using to get a list of values:

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse( pandltext );
var results = jObj.SelectTokens( "$..Rows.Row[?(@.type == 'Data')]..value" ).ToList();
```

Comment: Please post some examples of what you've tried, with code, and describe how it is not working as expected.

Comment: Also, post a valid/complete json, so that people can work on it.

Comment: Why don't you try to use regex ?

Comment: @Youssef13 you can deserialize to objects then use Linq. Why would you want to use regex for this.

Comment: @Youssef13 This JSON is structured data. When you have structured data with a well defined means of extracting what you want from it, there is no need for a regex. Just because something can be done with a regex doesn't mean it should. If you find yourself recommending regex's a lot, you might want to rethink the appropriateness.

Comment: @Youssef13 use the appropriate tool.  regex is not the appropriate tool here.

Comment: If you are going to downvote, can you at least give some constructive suggestions so I can improve my questions in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

var colData = jObj.SelectTokens("$..ColData")
                .Except(jObj.SelectTokens("$..Summary.ColData"))
                .ToList();
```

**EDIT**

```
foreach(var item in colData)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("=", item.Select(x => x["value"])));
}
```

or

```
var finalList = colData.Select(item => item.Select(x => (string)x["value"]).ToList())
               .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Eser. I used this as a starting point to get a list of values, but I'm still trying to make it usable. Using the code from your answer I get a value that looks like this `{[
  {
    "value": "Design income",
    "id": "82"
  },
  {
    "value": "975.00"
  }
]}` and I haven't been able to access the values from the list. I need "Design Income" and "975.00".

Comment: @mack *Take the tricky part of the answer into your question and extend your question with your new inability*. Is this the way of asking a question? Anyway I updated the answer once and far all.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to answer this. I wasn't intending to change the question with my edit, only add new information to the original question. Sorry if that changed the original question. Thanks again for your help. Your answer got me moving in the right direction again.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class Option
    {
         public string Name { get; set; }
         public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Header
    {
        public DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string ReportName { get; set; }
        public string ReportBasis { get; set; }
        public string StartPeriod { get; set; }
        public string EndPeriod { get; set; }
        public string SummarizeColumnsBy { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public IList<Option> Option { get; set; }
    }

    public class MetaData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Column
    {
        public string ColTitle { get; set; }
        public string ColType { get; set; }
        public IList<MetaData> MetaData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Columns
    {
        public IList<Column> Column { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColData
    {
         public string value { get; set; }
         public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColData
    {
         public string value { get; set; }
         public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public IList<ColData> ColData { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rows
    {
        public IList<Row> Row { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColData
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Summary
    {
        public IList<ColData> ColData { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColData
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public  Header { get; set; }
        public Rows Rows { get; set; }
        public Summary Summary { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public IList<ColData> ColData { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rows
    {
        public IList<Row> Row { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public IList<ColData> ColData { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public  Header { get; set; }
        public Rows Rows { get; set; }
        public  Summary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rows
    {
        public IList<Row> Row { get; set; }
    }

    public class Row
    {
        public  Header { get; set; }
        public Rows Rows { get; set; }
        public  Summary { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string group { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rows
    {
        public IList<Row> Row { get; set; }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public Header Header { get; set; }
        public Columns Columns { get; set; }
        public Rows Rows { get; set; }
    }
```

and use it with :

```
Example results =  Newtonsoft.JSON.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Example>(json);
```